# does odbc connection send encrypted password to server

Tags: database, connection, odbc

i am working on a new project that needs it's passwords to be encrypted so i want to know that does ODBC connection in windows send password to the server in encrypted form or in textual form.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with ODBC really. If you are talking about sending a password over a network to a remote database server then you need to look at the ODBC Driver you are using and whatever encryption your database server supports for network transports.

Comment: actually i m using it in data stage to extract data from sources so i wanted to make your that the odbc connection that i make is secure and its passwords are encrypted or not.

Comment: My answer stands. It has nothing to do with data stage. You need to look at the ODBC drivers you are using and the databases you are going to.

Comment: hey bohica i have one more thing to ask that is in DB2 ODBC driver i need to enable encryption on that. i am unable to find its configuration  file in which i can manually enable encryption.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use DB2. Search here for the answer and if you cannot find it ask a new question.